# selectnav.js : Label show but not selected in first page in site ( homepage )

Tags: menu, navigation, responsive-design

script : [Selectnav Github](http://lukaszfiszer.github.com/selectnav.js/)

when use selectnav , the (label) show in select but not be selected in first load index page (homepage)  but the selected link is  the first link after (label) ?

the select menu show in code that:

```
  <select class="selectnav" id="selectnav1">
  <option value="">- Navigation Menu - </option>
  <option value="index.html" selected="">Home</option>
```

You will see the class (selected) in Home link, not label link.

My custom js using for selectnav:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
  selectnav('nav', {
  label: '- Navigation Menu - ',
  nested: true,
  indent: '-'
});
});
```

my ul list structure  example  that:

```
 <ul id="nav" >
    <li><a href="index.html" class="active">Home</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#1">Home 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#2">Home 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#3">Home 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#4">Slider 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#5">Slider 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#6">Slider 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#7">Pages</a></li>
    <li><a href="#8">Features</a></li>
    <li><a href="#9">Portfolio</a> </li>
    <li><a href="blog.html">Blog</a> </li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have probably solved this issue by now, but if any one else stumbles upon this page see the below for a fix:

```
selectnav('nav',{
label: 'Navigation',
activeclass: false, // Default value is true
autoselect: false // Default value true
});
```